# Extract nested type information from ConstructorInfo of generics-sop

Tags: haskell, generics

I'm trying to learn the Haskell package [generics-sop](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.5.0.0) and in particular I'm using the helper method `constructorInfo` to get process-able information about a data type.

As an exercise I'm trying to extract information from the ConstructorInfo type into a more understandable type:

```hs
module SOPExperiment where

import qualified GHC.Generics as GHC
import Generics.SOP
import Data.Text (Text, pack)

data SimpleTree = Nil
  | Node String SimpleTree SimpleTree
  deriving (Show, GHC.Generic)

instance Generic SimpleTree
instance HasDatatypeInfo SimpleTree

data Exp = Union SimpleTree
  | Intersection SimpleTree
  deriving (Show, GHC.Generic)

instance Generic Exp
instance HasDatatypeInfo Exp
```

I've been able to piece together this partial solution `consNames`, that lists constructors of `Exp`:

```
-- This will give ["Union","Intersection"]
expConsNames = consNames (Proxy :: Proxy Exp)

-- And this ["Nil","Node"]
treeConsNames = consNames (Proxy :: Proxy SimpleTree)

consNames :: HasDatatypeInfo a => Proxy a -> [Text]
consNames p = hcollapse $ hliftA constructorNames cI :: [Text]
  where
  dI = datatypeInfo p
  cI = constructorInfo dI
  constructorNames :: ConstructorInfo xs -> K Text xs
  constructorNames cInfo =
      let cName = case cInfo of
              Constructor n -> n
              Infix n _ _   -> n
              Record n _    -> n
      in K . pack $ cName
```

1. **But how to return a list that includes nested constructor names?**

```hs
-- Should return ["Union","Intersection", "Nil", "Node"]
nestedExpConsNames = undefined
```

2. **Or slightly better, return a tree data type that represent how constructors are nested in the type?**

```
data Tree = Tree String [Tree] deriving Show
expDataStructure :: Tree
expDataStructure = undefined

{- Result should be something akin to (infinite tree): 
expDataStructure' = Tree "Exp" [
  Tree "Union" [
    Tree "SimpleTree" [Tree "Nil" [], Tree "Node" [Tree "SimpleTree" [...]]],
    Tree "SimpleTree" [Tree "Nil" [], Tree "Node" [Tree "SimpleTree" [...]]]
  ],
  Tree "Intersection" [
    Tree "SimpleTree" [Tree "Nil" [], Tree "Node" [Tree "SimpleTree" [...]]],
    Tree "SimpleTree" [Tree "Nil" [], Tree "Node" [Tree "SimpleTree" [...]]]
  ]]
  -}
```

Used GHC Extensions are: OverloadedStrings, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeFamilies, RankNTypes, TypeOperators, ConstraintKinds, MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, DefaultSignatures, DataKinds, DeriveGeneric, ExtendedDefaultRules

(All extensions might not be needed)

Comment: The problem here is that sub-types of a given constructor are not guaranteed to also have instances of `HasDatatypeInfo`, so you can't necessarily traverse them in the same way. You can get access to the sub-types themselves via the `xs` list in `ConstructorInfo xs`, and you can use `para_SList` to fold over them, but you can't query whether each type has a `HasDatatypeInfo` instance as you do that. This is a pretty standard problem when trying to do dependent type-ish things in Haskell. There is no real RTTI. It may sometimes almost look like there is, but it's all smoke and mirrors.

Comment: Hmm, all the necessary type information should be available at compile time right? I'm thinking I should be able to constrain with All or All2 constraints to `HasDatatypeInfo` types.

Comment: `ConstructorInfo` is at the term level, that's where types stop flowing. You can't require that the types wrapped inside `ConstructorInfo` have any constraints which are not already part of `ConstructorInfo` definition. And `HasDatatypeInfo` cannot be part of it, because then it would be impossible to construct `ConstructorInfo` for constructors that wrap any `HasDatatypeInfo`-lacking types.

Comment: I'm puzzled by how `HasDatatypeInfo` is different to classes like `Show` in this regard. Deriving `Show` only works when all nested types are also in `Show`. Can I somehow make a class `HasDatatypeInfo2` that enforce my instances to implement `HasDatatypeInfo` "all the way down"?

Comment: There's a lot here. First, the difference is that the compiler can automatically generate (i.e "derive") instances of `Show` for you. If you ask the compiler to do so, it will indeed require that all included types already have a `Show` instance. But only immediately included ones, _not_ all the way down. If, on the other hand, you don't ask the compiler to derive `Show` instances for you, but implement them manually instead, then there is no requirement of "all the way down". The class itself does not have this requirement, only the compiler's derivation mechanism.

Comment: But the answer to your second question is yes: you can certainly set up a system of classes that will require recursion all the way down. But those will not be the same as `generics-sop`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variant of the non-recursive function is required to define the recursive version, so let's start with that:

```
conNames_NP :: (Generic a, HasDatatypeInfo a) => Proxy a -> NP (K Text) (Code a)
conNames_NP p =
  map_NP
    (K . pack . constructorName)
    (constructorInfo (datatypeInfo p))
```

It's mostly what you wrote, but the case distinction is not needed, because `constructorName` is provided by the library.

Now let's define the recursive tree-based version, which will in general return an infinite tree. Also, in your example, datatype names suddenly appear in the tree structure. The semantics of that is unclear to me, so I'll produce a tree with only constructor names.

```
data Tree = Tree Text [Tree]
```

You need an additional class for all datatypes supporting this operation. This is because, as already brought up in the comments, you cannot (or better, don't want to) assume that every type recursively is an instance of `Generic` and `HasDatatypeInfo`. Primitive types such as `Char` or `Text` are not instances of these classes, yet they will probably occur in your datatypes somewhere.

So we define

```
class ConNamesRecursive a where
  conNamesRecursive :: Proxy a -> [Tree]
  default conNamesRecursive ::
    (Generic a, HasDatatypeInfo a, All2 ConNamesRecursive (Code a))
    => Proxy a -> [Tree]
  conNamesRecursive = gconNamesRecursive
```

The proxy is a matter of taste, as I'll be using type applications in the code below. I like to have proxies around as a reminder that a type argument will be needed.

The definition of `gconNamesRecursive` is only tricky because constructor names are not intrinsically tied to the type they are a constructor from, so we have to somehow pass the type info correctly. I do this by introducing a number of helper functions:

```
gconNamesRecursive ::
  forall a . (Generic a, HasDatatypeInfo a, All2 ConNamesRecursive (Code a))
  => Proxy a -> [Tree]
gconNamesRecursive p =
  collapse_NP (cmap_NP (Proxy @(All ConNamesRecursive)) go (conNames_NP p))
  where
    go :: forall xs . All ConNamesRecursive xs => K Text xs -> K Tree xs
    go = mapKK (\ cn -> Tree cn (concat (collapse_NP (conNamesRecursive_NP @xs))))
```

The generic definition starts from `conNames_NP` which is an n-ary product containing each constructor name for the top-level type, i.e., a `NP (K Text) (Code a)`. If we map over this (using `cmap_NP`), we have to say what to do with the code corresponding to each constructor. This is handled by `go`. That function turns the name into the root of a `Tree`, and the children are given by calling `conNamesRecursive_NP`, which is defined as follows:

```
conNamesRecursive_NP :: forall xs . All ConNamesRecursive xs => NP (K [Tree]) xs
conNamesRecursive_NP =
  cpure_NP (Proxy @ConNamesRecursive) go
  where
    go :: forall a . ConNamesRecursive a => K [Tree] a
    go = K (conNamesRecursive (Proxy @a))
```

This is a function just calling `conNamesRecursive` again per component of the constructor. Because this function is a member of the type class, we have to require in the beginning that all components occurring in the code of the original datatype are themselves members of this class.

Before we can use this on concrete example types, we have to make them (and all types that occur somewhere inside) an instance of `ConNamesRecursive`.

We can do this by just using `DeriveAnyClass`:

```
data SimpleTree =
    Nil
  | Node Text SimpleTree SimpleTree
  deriving (Show, GHC.Generic, Generic, HasDatatypeInfo, ConNamesRecursive)

data Exp =
    Union SimpleTree
  | Intersection SimpleTree
  deriving (Show, GHC.Generic, Generic, HasDatatypeInfo, ConNamesRecursive)
```

Note that I changed `String` to `Text` in `Node` so that I don't have to decide what to do with lists of characters, but can just treat `Text` as an abstract type. Abstract types can be made members of the `ConNamesRecursive` class producing an empty list of trees.

```
instance ConNamesRecursive Text where
  conNamesRecursive _ = []
```

Finally, in order to make this a bit easier to visualise, I implemented a (naive) `unDup` function on trees that stops if a constructor occurs underneath itself:

```
unDup :: [Tree] -> [Tree]
unDup = go Set.empty
  where
    go :: Set.Set Text -> [Tree] -> [Tree]
    go seen ts =
      map
        (\ (Tree cn children) ->
          Tree cn (if cn `Set.member` seen then [] else go (Set.insert cn seen) children)
        )
        ts
```

Now we can test:

```
GHCi> unDup $ conNamesRecursive (Proxy @Exp)
[Tree "Union"
  [Tree "Nil" []
  ,Tree "Node"
    [Tree "Nil" []
    ,Tree "Node" []
    ,Tree "Nil" []
    ,Tree "Node" []
    ]
  ]
  ,Tree "Intersection"
    [Tree "Nil" []
    ,Tree "Node"
      [Tree "Nil" []
      ,Tree "Node" []
      ,Tree "Nil" []
      ,Tree "Node" []
    ]
  ]
]
```

(Layout added for readability.)

Of course, all sorts of variations are possible to implement here.

As I said before, this function is somewhat trickier to define than most generic functions, because we're neither consuming a value of the type we analyze nor are we producing a value of the type we analyze, but we're producing a value of a constant type `[Tree]`, so there's little type information for GHC to go on, which means more type parameters / helper functions with type signatures than usual.

I hope this nevertheless gives you an idea.

Comment: Awesome write up and response! Now I need unknown time to absorb this. :)